# How do I ignore files in mercurial which has already been tracked?

Tags: mercurial, glob, hgignore

So what I really wish to do is to ignore some files that have already been added committed and pushed in the repository in mercurial .I have a project with the following directory structure.

```
Project X
    Project X a
       bin
       res
       src
       .hg
       .hgignore
```

Now all the files in the Project X has been tracked by mercurial . Now I want to ignore /bin and /res folder

Here is my glob syntax to ignore these directories in .hgignore file.

```
syntax: glob

/bin
/gen
```

Also i executed the following command to tell mercurial to forget the previously tracked unwanted files

```
hg forget /bin
hg forget /res
```

However mercurial still is tracking both of these folders.I am sort of lost here.Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: the easiest way is to tell Mercurial to *forget* the files (by using `hg forget`).

However Mercurial is not tracking directories, only files. You cannot *add* a directory and thus cannot *forget* it either. You probably have files under `bin` and `res` that have been added to the list of tracked files: those are the ones you need to forget.